# Facing error during query execution

Tags: sql-server, syntax

I wrote a query in which I want to merge two tables and also create a log table for the data.

[image: The query]

as you can see at first I declared the `@DimvisitorLog`. This is for data log
I checked all type of fields and the are all ok. I mean there is nothing wrong with matching datatypes but I face this error:

[image: Error while executing the query]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of changes I would make

```
Declare @DimVistorLog TABLE 
     (ActionX       VARCHAR(50)
     ,VisitorCode   INT
     ,VisitorName   VARCHAR(120)
     ,Stamp         DATETIME        DEFAULT(GETDATE())  --<-- use default value here
     );
```

Inside your merge statement in the output .. into clause Explicitly mention the column names for `@DimVistorLog` table. This is the reason you are getting the error.

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
 THEN INSERT  (VisitorName)
 VALUES (Source.VisitorName)    

  OUTPUT $actoin , inserted.VisitorName , inserted.VistorCode
       --<-- Explicitly mention the column names here -->--
    INTO @DimVistorLog (ActionX , VisitorName, VisitorCode)
```

And finally your log insert should look something like....

```
INSERT INTO SalesTrainingDW.dbo.VisitorLog (VisitorCode , VisitorName, ActionX, Stamp)
SELECT VisitorCode , VisitorName, ActionX, Stamp
FROM @DimVistorLog
WHERE ActionX = 'Insert'
```

*Note*

You are doing an Insert here, `deleted` would have nothing in it and it will always return null.

Delete is only useful when you are deleting or updating data, when deleting the delete values can be returned using delete.xxx and when updating the old values can be returned using the deleted.xxx.

But you have no use for deleted in your case since you are only inserting, you should be using `inserted`.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you need to also insert the `visitorcode`; and your spacing looks weird in the image.

```
merge SalesTrainingDW.dbo.Visitor      as target
  using SalesTrainingStage.dbo.Visitor as source
     on   target.VisitorCode =  source.VisitorCode 
      and target.VisitorName <> source.VisitorName
      when not matched then insert (VisitorCode, VisitorName)
        values (source.VisitorCode, source.VisitorName)
      --output $action, deleted.VisitorCode, deleted.VisitorName --changed to reflect M. Ali's point 
      output $action, inserted.VisitorCode, inserted.VisitorName 
        into @DimVisitorLog (ActionX, VisitorCode, VisitorName);

insert into SalesTrainingDW.dbo.VisitorLOG (VisitorCode, VisitorName, ActionX, stamp)
select VisitorCode, VisitorName, Actionx, stamp=getdate()
  from @DimVisitorLog 
  where ActionX = 'insert';  --changed to reflect M. Ali's point
```

You can also skip the table variable like this:

```
insert into SalesTrainingDW.dbo.VisitorLOG (VisitorCode, VisitorName, ActionX, stamp)
  select VisitorCode, VisitorName, ActionX, stamp=getdate()
  from (
    merge SalesTrainingDW.dbo.Visitor      as target
      using SalesTrainingStage.dbo.Visitor as source
         on   target.VisitorCode =  source.VisitorCode 
          and target.VisitorName <> source.VisitorName
          when not matched then insert (VisitorCode, VisitorName)
            values (source.VisitorCode, source.VisitorName)
          --output $action, deleted.VisitorCode, deleted.VisitorName --changed to reflect M. Ali's point 
          output $action, inserted.VisitorCode, inserted.VisitorName
      ) as i (ActionX, VisitorCode, VisitorName)
      where ActionX = 'insert'
```

Since this operation is only inserting values, you can skip `merge` and do an `insert`. Unless you are going to use the [extra options `merge` gives you on output](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2012/06/12/merge-gives-better-output-options/):

```
insert SalesTrainingDW.dbo.Visitor (VisitorCode, VisitorName)
  output ActionX='insert', inserted.VisitorCode, inserted.VisitorName, stamp=getdate()
    into @DimVisitorLog (ActionX, VisitorCode, VisitorName, stamp)
  select  VisitorCode, VisitorName
    from  SalesTrainingStage.dbo.Visitor s
      where not exists ()
        select 1 
          from SalesTrainingDW.dbo.Visitor v 
          where s.visitorcode=v.visitorcode 
          and s.visitorname=v.visitorname
          );
```

or with a `left join` instead of `not exists`:

```
insert SalesTrainingDW.dbo.Visitor (VisitorCode, VisitorName)
  output ActionX='insert', inserted.VisitorCode, inserted.VisitorName, stamp=getdate()
    into @DimVisitorLog (ActionX, VisitorCode, VisitorName, stamp)
  select  VisitorCode, VisitorName
    from  SalesTrainingStage.dbo.Visitor s
      left join SalesTrainingDW.dbo.Visitor v on s.visitorcode=v.visitorcode and s.visitorname=v.visitorname
    where v.visitorcode is null;
```

and you could also skip the table variable with either of those inserts:

```
insert into SalesTrainingDW.dbo.VisitorLOG (VisitorCode, VisitorName, ActionX, stamp)
  select i.VisitorCode, i.VisitorName,  ActionX = 'insert', stamp=getdate()
  from (
    insert SalesTrainingDW.dbo.Visitor (VisitorCode, VisitorName)
      output inserted.VisitorCode, inserted.VisitorName
      select  VisitorCode, VisitorName
        from  SalesTrainingStage.dbo.Visitor s
        where not exists (
          select 1 
            from SalesTrainingDW.dbo.Visitor v 
            where s.visitorcode=v.visitorcode 
              and s.visitorname=v.visitorname
              )
  ) as i;
```